# Problem accessing static resource in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I am accessing my static resource using `apex:image`

```
<apex:image url="https://test.salesforce.com{!$Resource.payment}" width="50" height="50"/>
```

When I take out the `https://test.salesforce.com` from the url the image does not show up. On inspecting without salesforce url  it looks like the image is coming from  some other site `https://abc.xyz.com/resource/id/payment(cant disclose original url)`.

Comment: Why not using `<apex:includeScript>`?

Comment: @Lance didnot work either

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<apex:image url="{!$Resource.payment}" width="50" height="50"/>
```

More on [referencing static resource in vf markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm).

Comment: this is the first thing i tried it did not work

Comment: What is MIME Type of your static resource payment

Comment: MIME Type image/jpeg

Comment: Are you showing this image in a panel or pageblock something like that

Comment: no just showing it in html div

Answer (score 1):

Use URLFOR and ensure the access level of the Resource is set to public

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.payment)}" width="50" height="50"/>
```

Which will resolve the complete URL regardless of where the page is accessed from, SF, Community, Site, etc

Comment: Did not work tried it already